# Python script system call error

Tags: python, matlab

I'm working around some legacy software that runs in Matlab, whereas I'm using Python.

Simplest way I've found is to call the python script from Matlab as follows:

```
dos("myscript.py")
```

However I've suddenly got the following error with a specific python file:

```
'D:\********.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Other python scripts are still working fine using this approach - including a local version of the file I'm having the issue with.

The error and other things working suggests this is a windows issue? My system is 64-bit windows 7 professional and my Python installation is 64-bit Python 2.7.xxx installed using Anaconda 2.2.0.

Ben

Comment: Are there characters present in this filename that aren't present in others that function correctly?

Comment: No - as I said a local version of the file from when I'd originally developed it, worked fine

Comment: Are you calling it from a mapped network drive?

Comment: No it's a local directory, but created (and the file copied from) source control on a network location.

Comment: Is it owned by another user or marked as non-executable?

Comment: `'D:\********.py'` -- you're not forgetting to make it a raw string or double your backslashes, are you?

Comment: The call is from Matlab so the string is correct. The thing that's changed is that it's a copy downloaded via source control. The fact that my original works, makes me think Patrick is correct in wondering if it's owned by another user